# Firebase data comparison without waste of bandwidth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

is it possible to check if a base64 string on a phone differs from the one in a firebase database without downloading the actual base64 string from the database?

Also if that's not possible, would it be possible to do similar comparison with an image file inside the firebase storage?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that firebase stores local information that is accessible to your application when it does not have connection and synchs up with the remote version of it when it does have connection if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: You'd typically compare hash values between the client and the storage layer to accomplish this. So: 1) calculate the hash value of the image client-side, 2) check if a node/file with that hash value already exists in the database/storage, 3) add the node/file if not.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). It would help to state the real goal here and we could work on solutions to that. The best option, as mentioned, would be to store hashes and compare those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In the database: Not without downloading the base64 strings and comparing them, or storing hashes and comparing those. On a side note, please don't store files in the database, it's not very efficient and significantly more expensive than using storage.

2) In storage: [Get the file metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata) and compare the file hashes (crc32c and md5 are both available). That way you're not downloading the entire object to compare it.